# Clustered Index being used over non-clustered with same key

Tags: sql-server, index, clustered-index, nonclustered-index

I have a table that has a clustered index (CI) on the field filename.

It also has a non-clustered index (NCI) - With the key column of filename and 5 other columns in the includes. (There are additional fields in the table)

I want to change the clustered index to an INT ID column removing filename (nvarchar(255)), but when I checked the usage stats the CI actually gets used more than the NCI.

Can anyone help me understand why the CI would get used over the NCI? And also let me know if it would be safe to change the CI to the INT ID column and assume the NCI would satisfy any queries originally using the CI? I have included the details of both indexes below:
[image: Indexes]

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Index usage depends much on the queries. Add sample queries to your question that use the different indexes.

Comment: If a query references `filename` and any other columns _not_ included in the NCI, clearly using the CI would be preferable.

Comment: [How To Get Answers To SQL Server Performance Questions](https://www.erikdarlingdata.com/how-to-get-answers-to-sql-server-performance-questions/)

Comment: The clustered index *includes* all columns of the table, because it actually **is** the table itself. A nonclustered index is a copy of the table for the fields you specify in the index definition. Therefore your nonclustered index is currently redundant to your clustered index, being a subset of the clustered index. Like Dan said, without seeing the queries using those indexes, no one can tell you if it's safe to make the change. (If there's a column your query uses that is not part of the nonclustered index definition, then it may not be safe to make your proposed change.)